# A question on Stokes theorem for Lipschitz functions

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be an oriented compact Riemannian manifold. Let $f$ be a Lipschitz function on $M$, denote $M'\subset M$ be the set on which $f$ is differentiable.

On one hand, Stokes theorem works for Lipschitz functions, so we have
$$0=\int_M \Delta f.$$

On the other hand I was wondering do we have
$$\int_M\Delta f=\int_{M'}\Delta f\ \ ?$$

In other words, if $f$ is Lipschitz on $M$, and $\Delta f\geq 0$ on $M'$, could we conclude that $f$ has to be a constant?

Comment: Are you aware of Rademacher's theorem? Maybe it can be applied on manifolds too (but this is only a guess).

Comment: @ Crostul Yes I know that, so $M\backslash M'$ has measure zero.

Comment: What do you mean by $\Delta f$? Is it the Laplace-Beltrami operator? If so, how can you integrate it over $M$? Also, I am not sure Rademacher holds in this generality.

Comment: @ Silvia Ghinassi Yes it is the Baltrami-Laplace operator. Rademacher's theorem holds for functions on manifolds too, but in my question $\Delta f$ is not Lipschitz.

Comment: Are you sure that Stoke's theorem holds for non-derivable Lipschitz functions? In order to apply it, you should remove the points where $f$ is not derivable. First: this is not necessarily a manifold anymore. Second: if it is, it might acquire a boundary, producing boundary terms. Third: the restriction of $f$ to this set might not have compact support anymore.

Comment: @twinkletwinklelittlestar sorry I read late, when you tag an user you need not to put the space, otherwise they won't get a notification. Anyway, now unrelated, but I checked, Rademacher's theorem holds for Lipschitz maps on Lipschitz manifold.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is only Lipschitz continuous, then $\Delta f$ is not in general an $L^2$ function. Instead, it has to be interpreted as a distribution. (For example, on $\mathbb R$, the Laplacian of $|x|$ is a delta distribution concentrated at the origin.) It follows easily from the definition of distributional derivatives that $\int_M\Delta f=0$ for any $L^2$ function (indeed, any distribution) $f$.

When integrating a distribution, it's definitely not OK to throw out sets of measure zero. (Think about the delta distribution, for example.)

To address your main question, I think it might be true that if $f$ is Lipschitz and $\Delta f\ge 0$ in the distributional sense (which means that $\int_M \phi\Delta f \ge 0$ for any smooth nonnegative test function $\phi$), then $f$ is constant. But I don't have time to look it up right now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will check the details by myself.

Comment: @JackLee Just to clarify, since I am not familiar with the notation, is $\int_M \Delta f$ intended as a current? If not, how do we interpret it without integrating against a volume form?

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi: I was just using $\int_M \Delta f$ as a shorthand notation for $\int_M \Delta f\, dV$, because that's the notation the OP was using.